# Trying to copy entire object for older browsers that don't support jquery

Tags: javascript, object, copy

I created a box with a red border with the word Abc in it. What I want is another box exactly the same but moved in 100 pixels from the left and 100 pixels from the top with the ID of the new div set to Y and the vari property of the new object set to 2. I'm able to set the value of vari but as soon as I try to change DIV elements of the copied box (object.htmlE), I get a javascript error that it cannot convert COPIEDBOX.htmlE to an object, yet BOX.htmlE is an object (or at least the interpreter thinks so if I set BOX.htmlE.id for example).

How do I fix this so that everything about BOX gets copied over to COPIEDBOX?

```js
function specialobject() {
  this.vari = 1;
  this.htmlE = document.getElementById('X');
  this.htmlE.onclick = new Function("alert('X clicked')");
  this.htmlE.style.border = '1px solid red';
  this.htmlE.style.width = '100px';
  this.htmlE.style.height = '100px';
}


function cloneObject(iteminobject, oldcollection) {
  if (typeof(iteminobject) !== "object" || iteminobject === null) {
    return iteminobject;
  }
  if (oldcollection.iteminobject == 1) { //trying to prevent recursion
    return;
  }
  oldcollection.iteminobject = 1;
  var copieditems = {};
  for (var i in iteminobject) {
    copieditems[i] = cloneObject(iteminobject[i], oldcollection);
  }
  return copieditems;
}

var BOX = {},
  COPIEDBOX = {},
  OLD = {};
BOX = new specialobject();
document.body.appendChild(BOX.htmlE);
COPIEDBOX = cloneObject(BOX, OLD);
COPIEDBOX.vari = 2;
COPIEDBOX.htmlE.id = 'Y';
COPIEDBOX.htmlE.style.left = '100px';
COPIEDBOX.htmlE.style.top = '100px';
document.body.appendChild(COPIEDBOX.htmlE);
```

```html
<div ID="X">Abc</div>
```

** UPDATED **

Excuse my formatting if it isn't appealing, but I added a custom object within my object and it seems copying custom objects are fine but copying actual HTML elements are a nightmare. this is my code:

```
<div ID="X">Abc</div>
<script>
function o2(){
this.special=1;
}

function specialobject(){
    this.vari=1;
    this.something=new o2();
    this.htmlE=document.getElementById('X');
    this.htmlE.onclick=new Function("alert('X clicked')");
    this.htmlE.style.border='1px solid red';
    this.htmlE.style.width='100px';
    this.htmlE.style.height='100px';
}


function cloneObject(iteminobject){
  if(typeof(iteminobject)!=="object" || iteminobject===null){
    return iteminobject;
  }
  if (old[iteminobject]==1){ //trying to prevent recursion
    return;
  }
  old[iteminobject]=1;
  var copieditems={};
  for(var i in iteminobject){
    copieditems[i]=cloneObject(iteminobject[i]);
  }
  return copieditems;
}
console.trace;
var BOX={},COPIEDBOX={},old={};
BOX=new specialobject();
document.body.appendChild(BOX.htmlE);
BOX.htmlE.id='Z';
COPIEDBOX=cloneObject(BOX);
COPIEDBOX.vari=2;
COPIEDBOX.htmlE.id='Y';
COPIEDBOX.htmlE.style.left='100px';
COPIEDBOX.htmlE.style.top='100px';
document.body.appendChild(COPIEDBOX.htmlE);
</script>
```

Comment: What browsers doesn't jQuery support? https://jquery.com/browser-support/ says that jQuery 1.x supports IE 6+

Comment: Disregarding the odd code formatting and other bits, did you at least try to debug this? It looks quite obvious what's wrong here, so what isn't clear to you?

Comment: Then my browser must be garbage in error detecting.

Comment: When you perform the recursive call, `oldcollection.iteminobject` is `1`, so it returns. So `copieditems` all the properties in `copieditems` are undefined.

Comment: @Mike Set a breakpoint after the call to `cloneObject`, and then look at the value of `COPIEDBOX`.